# Flipping a div just not working inside rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Hello I am a newbie javascript/jquery programmer. I have a page with a div and on click I need the div to flip in one direction and its just not happening. I am doing all of this within a rails app. Please help. It works perfectly on fiddle as posted by someone else : [http://jsfiddle.net/nicooprat/GDdtS/][1] All i am doing is adapting this into my rails app but with no results.

Here is my code so far

In the view : template.html.erb

```
    <div class="flip"> 
          <div class="card"> 
              <div class="face front"> 
                  Front
                  <!-- I have an elaborate div here in this block -->
              </div> 
              <div class="face back"> 
                  Back
                    <!-- I have a 1-1 mirror mapping of front div here in this block -->
              </div> 
          </div> 
      </div>
 <hr>
```

Here's the associated css of the view. In fact all of this work on fiddle. Just not within my rails app.

template.css.scss

```
.flip {
  -webkit-perspective: 800;
   width: 400px;
   height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
.flip .card.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
}
.flip .card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}
.flip .card .face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden ;
  z-index: 2;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 3em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
}
.flip .card .front {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.flip .card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotatex(-180deg);
    background: blue;
    background: white;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Finally Here is the Javascript :
template.js

```
$('.flip').click(function(){
       alert("hello"); <-- never called. 
       $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).removeClass('flipped');
       });
       return false;
   });
```

Comment: Are you sure that proper css and js files are included in the page?

Comment: Phil if i remove all the javascript code and just leave the alert("hello") it executes properly. This is why i am so baffled.

Comment: ok i figured it out. Its missting $(document).ready(function()
{
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap your code into `$(document).ready` block. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.flip').click(function(){
       alert("hello"); <-- never called. 
       $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').mouseleave(function(){
           $(this).removeClass('flipped');
       });
       return false;
     });
})
```

Comment: Thanks Phil! I accept this answer. Bonus points if you will tell me wht this document ready thing does for me inside the rails app.

Comment: Just because you want this js to be executed AFTER the page loads. If you don't put document ready it is executing BEFORE the page load and doesn't find the $(".flip") element